# Excel VBA Combine Duplicates Keep Unique

Tags: vba, merge, duplicates, unique

I have a dataset that I paste just below a table in which it extends to include it. I then combine all duplicate rows. However, I added two additional columns to the table that i would like to have notes in. However, when I later combine the duplicate rows, the newer row's blank cells overwrite any notes I had in there. Columns AC and AD are my notes cells. I have been trying to use a concatenate method to get around it overwriting it, however I found this awesome macro to combine duplicates but I cant for the life of me figure out how to write a line that would not delete my notes columns in the combine process! Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
Option Explicit

Sub removeDupesKeepLast()
Dim d As Long, dDQs As Object, ky As Variant
Dim r As Long, c As Long, vVALs As Variant, vTMP As Variant

'appTGGL bTGGL:=False   'uncomment this when you have finished debugging

Set dDQs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dDQs.comparemode = vbTextCompare

'step 1 - bulk load the values
With Worksheets("Master RFL Pipeline").Range("Table135")   'you should know what worksheet you are on
    With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion 'block of data radiating out from A1
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0) 'step off the header row
            vVALs = .Value  'use .Value2 if you do not have dates in unformatted cells
        End With
    End With
End With

'step 2 - build the dictionary
ReDim vTMP(UBound(vVALs, 2) - 1)
For r = LBound(vVALs, 1) To UBound(vVALs, 1)
    For c = LBound(vVALs, 2) To UBound(vVALs, 2)
        vTMP(c - 1) = vVALs(r, c)
    Next c
    dDQs.Item(vVALs(r, 1) & ChrW(8203)) = vTMP
Next r

'step 3 - put the de-duplicated values back into the array
r = 0
ReDim vVALs(1 To dDQs.Count, LBound(vVALs, 2) To UBound(vVALs, 2))
For Each ky In dDQs
    r = r + 1
    vTMP = dDQs.Item(ky)
    For c = LBound(vTMP) To UBound(vTMP)
        vVALs(r, c + 1) = vTMP(c)
    Next c
Next ky

'step 4 - clear the destination; put the de-duplicated values back into the worksheet and reset .UsedRange
With Worksheets("Master RFL Pipeline").Range("Table135")   'you should know what worksheet you are on
    With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion 'block of data radiating out from A1
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0) 'step off the header row
            .ClearContents  'retain formatting if it is there
            .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(vVALs, 1), UBound(vVALs, 2)) = vVALs
        End With
    End With
    .UsedRange   'assert the UsedRange property (refreshes it)
End With

dDQs.RemoveAll: Set dDQs = Nothing

appTGGL
End Sub

Public Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
    .EnableEvents = bTGGL
    .DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
    .AutoRecover.Enabled = bTGGL   'no interruptions with an auto-save
    .Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
    .CutCopyMode = False
    .StatusBar = vbNullString
End With
Debug.Print Timer
End Sub
```